# ConstraintLayout: square views, evenly distributed, autosized

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

How can I use ConstraintLayout to get 5 evenly distributed squares, with **flexible size** depending on screen width?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you already tried yourself to do this? Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Stack Overflow is not a coding service. You are expected to ***research your issue and make a good attempt to write the code yourself*** before posting. If you get stuck on something *specific*, come back and include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and a summary of what you tried, so we can help.

Comment: did you tried the solutions given here? Which one worked for you? thanks

Answer (score 32):

You need to create a chain of widgets that is connected on all sides of its parent container (you set the dimensions of this parent container to whatever you want/need). Each widget should have the `app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"` constraint to ensure a square pattern. For instance:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/frame2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/frame1"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/frame3"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame3"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/frame2"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Guidelines with precentage, something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:id="@+id/guideline"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="316dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.502" />

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:id="@+id/guideline2"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.2" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline2"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline3"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.502" />

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:id="@+id/guideline3"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.4" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline3"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline4"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.502" />

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:id="@+id/guideline4"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.6" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline4"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline5"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.503" />

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:id="@+id/guideline5"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.8" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button6"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline5"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

To add Guideline, right-click on ConstraintLayout / Add Vertical/Horisontal Guideline...
Hope it helps you

Cheers

Comment: Instead of Guidelines between the buttons, Spaces could also be used, with layout_constraintWidth_percent set to a desired fraction value.

Answer (score -1):

[image: Img. Vertical orientation]

[image: Img. Horizontal orientation]

You just need to add a constraint to the views to the first view. On both the top and bottom.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/uno"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/dos"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"/>

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/dos"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/tres"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/uno"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/uno"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/uno"/>

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/tres"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorAccent"
    app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/dos"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/uno"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/uno" />
```

Comment: I refer to this: app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/uno"        
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/uno"